# Security rules based on time limit in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

On Firebase, I have a field like this:

```
timeStamp: ”2016-06-03 13:39:27"
```

In the `Security & Rules` section, I want to set some permission to write based on the fact that the time has not gone over the limit set in the timeStamp field.
I can’t find examples similar to what I want to do on the net, and what I have tried (hereafter) did not work. To start from, I must be using the wrong syntax.

```
".write": "data.child('timeStamp').val() > now"
```

Does anyone knows how to do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `timeStamp`, use [Unix epoch time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (in milliseconds).

As per syntax error, it is difficult to determine without knowing the hierarchical structure of your data, but it looks fine in general.

You will also find the examples on Section #3 on [this page](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/quickstart.html) helpful.